Is there a way to develop an exchange transport agent like for 365/Azure?
I am currently looking for a way to hook all incoming emails in a 365 tenant.
For the moment, we only found the solution to have 1 hook per mailbox and being notified of incoming email, but this produce a lot of complexity (having 4000 users induce having 4000 web hooks, etc). Also, to have a more optimized, we are trying to achieve a similar behavior as the usual "Exchange Transport Agent" that exists with onprem exchanges, but not with 365 version (cloud).
Is there a way through Graph or whatever to develop such an agent that can "intercept" incoming email and tampering them for example ? (adding a header for example)
Idea would be to intercept every incoming message to analyze them, and avoid having multiple hooks to all user mailboxes.
Thanks a lot for help,
NB: I do not want to change MX to add a relay, I want the email to stay where they are :)

You can use "Mail Flow Rules"
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/mail-flow-rules

Thanks for answer, I looked on this and connectors, but there is very few documentation about connectors (how to handle emails and sent them back to the tenant).
